# ArcGIS geometryEngine.intersect always returns null

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am using the ArcGIS JavaScript API with the `geometryEngine.intersect()` method but I cannot get it to work on feature layers.

In [my code](https://codepen.io/josemvidal/pen/OejPwx?editors=1000) you can see how I can create and intersect 2 square geometries I created.

But, in that same code, I also try to intersect one of the squares with every one of the 271 features in the featureLayer and the `intersect()` method returns null for every single one of them, even thought the map clearly shows some of them intercept the square.

What am I doing wrong?

My code is below an also [in this codepen](https://codepen.io/josemvidal/pen/OejPwx?editors=1000), is:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>ArcGIS JavaScript Tutorials: Buffer and intersect geometry</title>
  <style>
    html, body, #viewDiv {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.11/esri/css/main.css">
  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.11"></script>

  <script>  
    require([
      "esri/Map",
      "esri/views/MapView",
      "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
      "esri/Graphic",
      "esri/geometry/geometryEngine",
      "esri/geometry/geometryEngineAsync"
    ], function(Map, MapView, FeatureLayer, Graphic, geometryEngine,
                 geometryEngineAsync) {
      var map = new Map({
        basemap: "topo-vector"
      });

      var view = new MapView({
        container: "viewDiv",
        map: map,
        center: [-118.80543,34.02700],
        zoom: 13
      });

      // Trails (lines)
      var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer({
        url: "https://services3.arcgis.com/GVgbJbqm8hXASVYi/arcgis/rest/services/Trails_Styled/FeatureServer/0"
      });

      map.add(featureLayer);

      let squareShape1 = {
        type: "polygon",
        rings: [
                [-118.8, 34.05],
                [-118.8, 34],
                [-118.9, 34],
                [-118.9, 34.05]
           ],
        spatialReference: featureLayer.spatialReference
        };
        let squareShape2 = {
        type: "polygon",
        rings: [
                [-118.75, 34.08],
                [-118.75, 34.03],
                [-118.85, 34.03],
                [-118.85, 34.08]
           ],
        spatialReference: featureLayer.spatialReference          
        };
        let redOutline = {
            type: "simple-fill",
            color: [227, 139, 79, 0.1],
            outline: {
                color: [255, 0, 0],
                width: 1
            }
        };
        let blueOutline = {
            type: "simple-fill",
            color: [0, 79, 200, 0.1],
            outline: {
                color: [0, 0, 255],
                width: 1
            }
        };      
        let squareA = new Graphic({
            geometry: squareShape1,
            symbol: redOutline
        }); 
        let squareB = new Graphic({
            geometry: squareShape2,
            symbol: redOutline
        });  

      view.graphics.add(squareA);
      view.graphics.add(squareB);

      // intersect the 2 squares, this works      
      geometryEngineAsync.intersect(squareA.geometry,squareB.geometry).then(
           function (result) {
               if (result) {
                   console.log("Found an Intersection among the squares!");
                   console.log(result);
                   let intersectionGraphic = new Graphic({
                       geometry: result,
                       symbol: blueOutline
                     });
                   view.graphics.add(intersectionGraphic); //show the intersection}
                } 
                else {
                    console.log("No Intersection");
                };
                }).catch(function (error) {
                            console.log("Error");
                            console.log(error);
       });  //intersect.catch

      // Intersect the features in the featureLayer with one of the squares
      // DOES NOT WORK. instersect() always returns null, but is should not.
      // Queries for all the features in the featureLayer, so we can intersect each one
      featureLayer.queryFeatures().then(function (results) {
          console.log("Got results");
          console.log(results);
          let layerGeometries = results.features.map(function (feature) {
              return feature.geometry;
          });
          console.log("Num geometries=" + layerGeometries.length);
          layerGeometries.forEach(function (geometry) {
//            console.log("g=");
//            console.log(geometry);
            geometryEngineAsync.intersect(squareA.geometry,geometry).then(
                function (result) {
                    if (result) {
                     console.log("Found an Intersection!");
                     console.log(result);
                     let intersectionGraphic = new Graphic({
                         geometry: result,
                         symbol: blueOutline
                         });
                     view.graphics.add(intersectionGraphic); //show the intersection}
                     } 
                     else {
                         console.log("No Intersection");
                     };
                 }).catch(function (error) {
                            console.log("Error");
                            console.log(error);
                      });  //catch         
              }); //forEach
              console.log("Done forEach");
       }); //queryFeatures.then
      console.log("Done queryFeatures");
    });    
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="viewDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the code above I expect it to print out "Found and Intersection!" a few times, but it never prints that out. It prints "No Intersection" 271 times instead.

Comment: So you left out the most important part: How the squares were created.  Without a common spatial reference, geometry operators always return false.

Comment: You can see the full code in the codepen https://codepen.io/josemvidal/pen/OejPwx?editors=1000 I am setting their spatialRerence to be the same as the one used by the featureLayer, lines 54 and 64. Is that wrong?

Comment: Third party links fail over time. If it's not in the question, it's not in the question.

Comment: Ok, I updated the question with the full code.

Comment: I would say that the problem could be here: geometryEngineAsync.intersect(squareA.geometry,geometry) what does geometry belong to?  For the function that works you have defined squareA and squareB. It seems to me that you want to use -- layerGeometries.geometry as a passed value. So  geometryEngineAsync.intersect(squareA.geometry,layerGeometries.geometry)

Comment: That does not work (you can try yourself in the codepen). layerGeometries is an array of Geometry objects, it does not have a .geometry object. The `geometry` variable iterates over all the Geometires in layerGeometries.

Comment: I think the problem is that the spatialReference of the square and the layer do not match. I thought my code above was setting them to match but, some logging shows that they don't. The square has the default geometry. How do I get the square to have the same geometry as the layer?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but I think I resolved this problem. Even though your `featureLayer`'s spatial reference is not WGS84, once initialised with a map, it gets reprojected to that (or whatever base map is assigned to the `map`). And then when you iterate over your geometries, they come as in their original spatial reference (102100). If you log the spatialReferences of the `geometry` and your shapes, you will see they are not equal (as suspected in the comments). The workaround is to re-project your square(s) just before the intersect operation, i.e., adding

`squareA.geometry.spatialReference = geometry.spatialReference`

just before

`geometryEngineAsync.intersect(squareA.geometry,geometry)`